# World and Map Frame for a real robot

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, mapping, transformation

I am trying to develop a robot for mapping purposes. Currently, I have a Velodyne VLP16 lidar and an IMU. I am having a bit of a confusion in stating the transforms of the system. For the lidar and IMU, the transforms are supposed to be static and I have defined them using the following:

```
static_transform_publisher x y z qx qy qz qw frame_id child_frame_id  period_in_ms
```

How do I define and publish world and amp frame? How do I define the dynamic transforms between world frame and base link?

Answer (score 3):

As you've figured, static transforms are valid for fixed offsets such as sensor positions. They are the minimal solution the more complete recommended solution is to setup a robot model. There's tutorials on that [here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials).

More directly towards your question on how to define the map to base link. That is generally referred to as localization. You will need to run a localization algorithm to keep track of where your robot is in the map. The most common ones are either done in a predefined map, like amcl or by a simultaneous localization and mapping (SLAM) algorithm.

There are a lot of tutorials for getting setup, but I recommend the core series here: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

Since you didn't clarify in your question if you're using ROS 2 there's a good entry point here: https://navigation.ros.org/ with [a first time robot setup guide.](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/index.html)

Comment: As a note for future reference. If you can provide more concrete details about what you're doing and how to reproduce it. It's easier for us to help answer your question. I mostly provided keywords for future research and pointers to resources since your question was very abstract. If you can provide a more complete question you can get a more complete answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am working on a cable driven robot which is deployed on a small agricultural farm. I have successfully integrated the static transforms however, I am unsure about how to publish the `/odom` frame. Which package should I use to publish odometry using IMU and GPS? I dont have encoder motor to estimate wheel odometry. And later, how do you suggest creating a map of the agricultural field?

Comment: Your follow up questions are very open ended and are going into [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) territory which are in appropriate for this site. Also please don't ask questions in comments.
I would recommend that you do some research on http://wiki.ros.org/agriculture and https://discourse.ros.org/c/ros-agriculture/63 about what others are doing and when you have a system that you have [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) please ask another question.